# How can I do correct UV for model?

Tags: uv

I have a model for which I am trying to create UV. I created seams in different places, but no way worked. More or less appropriate way is create UV Project from view, but with it the side parts are stretched. I need the texture to cover the entire model and not stretch. How to properly unwrap models of this shape?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark some seams on the corners, otherwise the UV map will be stretched:

[image]

Result:

[image]

From your current topology, simply unwrap with the *Conformal* option instead of *Angle Based*:

[image]

Comment: I do this with UV unwrap, but it's broke.
https://i.ibb.co/N22N3Rj/2.png

Comment: you need to orthogonalize your UV, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here it is https://pasteall.org/blend/1d370ba314db4bcca054c2c3242abb0b

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: It works if I need to show the model from one side. But what if it is used in animation?

Comment: What is the kind of texture you want to project onto the object? You may need to edit your image if you don't want any seam, there's no magic here, you can't do in 3D what you can't do in real life

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answers. I'll try to edit my texture.